# ¿Cómo implementar colisiones entre objetos y personajes en un juego HTML5/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Imagenes
[component2.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7nBF.jpg)
[link.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuA3T.png)**

```
Estoy trabajando en el desarrollo de un juego utilizando HTML5 y JavaScript, y me encuentro en la etapa de implementar colisiones entre mi personaje y varios objetos del entorno, como paredes, agua, árboles, etc. Actualmente, tengo un canvas donde se representa el juego y un personaje que se mueve con las teclas.

Me gustaría obtener orientación sobre cómo implementar colisiones de manera eficaz en mi juego. ¿Cuáles son las mejores prácticas y enfoques recomendados para gestionar colisiones de manera eficiente en juegos web? ¿Existen bibliotecas o técnicas específicas que deba considerar para lograr colisiones precisas y fluidas?
```

Mi objetivo es lograr colisiones precisas y realistas en mi juego, ya que son un aspecto fundamental para la jugabilidad y la experiencia del usuario. Sin embargo, me enfrento a desafíos en cuanto a la eficiencia y la precisión de las colisiones, especialmente en entornos con muchos objetos y personajes en movimiento.

Agradezco cualquier consejo, ejemplos de código o recursos que puedan proporcionarme para abordar este aspecto crucial de mi proyecto de juego. ¡Gracias de antemano por su ayuda!
**Aquí está mi código actual para el juego (incluyendo el movimiento del personaje):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>One chance</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="personaje.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="icon.png
    " type="image/x-icon">
    <style>

html, body {
            height: 80%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }


        /* Estilos para los elementos img */
        .npc-img {
            position: absolute;
            width: 90px;
            height: 90px;
            z-index: 2; /* Coloca los elementos por encima del canvas (z-index más alto) */
        }

        /* Estilos para el canvas */
        #CanvasG {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1; /* Coloca el canvas debajo de los elementos img (z-index más bajo) */
        }

        /* Estilos para el botón */
        #botonstats {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            left: 10px;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: #007BFF;
            color: white;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            z-index: 3; /* Coloca el botón delante de todos los elementos */
        }

        #botonClean{
            position: absolute;
            top: 50px;
            left: 50px;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: #007BFF;
            color: white;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            z-index: 3; /* Coloca el botón delante de todos los elementos */
        }
        
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="inicializar();" onkeydown="onKeyDown(event);" onkeyup="onKeyUp(event);">
    <!-- Botón para mostrar estadísticas -->
    <button id="botonstats" onclick="mostrarStats()">Mostrar Stats</button>
    <!-- Agrega un botón para ver y usar los ítems -->

<!-- Agrega un elemento para mostrar los ítems del inventario -->
<div id="inventario" style="display: none;"></div>


    <canvas id="CanvasG" width="1720" height="768"></canvas>

    <!-- Elemento para representar al personaje de Zelda -->
    <div id="personajeZelda" style="position: absolute; left: 1090px; top: 320px; width: 90px; height: 90px; cursor: pointer;"></div>

    <!-- Elementos img para representar a los NPCs -->
    <img src="zelda.png" class="npc-img" style="left: 1200px; top: 450px;" onclick="tocarZelda()">
    <img src="ladron.png" class="npc-img" style="left: 400px; top: 108px;" onclick="tocarLadron()">

    <!-- Div para mostrar estadísticas -->
    <div id="statsDiv" style="position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 20px;"></div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <script src="stats.js"></script>
    <script>
        var zeldaTocada = false; // Variable de control para rastrear si Zelda ha sido tocada
        var ladronTocado = false; // Variable de control para rastrear si has tocado al ladrón

        var canvasC = document.getElementById("CanvasG");
        var pant = canvasC.getContext("2d");
        var anchoPantalla = 1720;
        var altoPantalla = 768;
        var teclap = 0;
        var backgroundImg = new Image();
        backgroundImg.src = "component2.png";
        var sprite = new Image();
        sprite.src = "link.png";
        var indiceX = 0;
        var indiceY = 0;
        var linkX = 0;
        var linkY = 0;
        var personajeAnimado = false;
        var frameCount = 0;
        var velocidadAnimacion = 8; // Ajusta esta velocidad según tu preferencia

        function inicializar() {
            moverPersonaje(1090, 320);
            requestAnimationFrame(dibujaCanvas);

            // Agrega el evento onclick al personaje de Zelda
            var personajeZeldaDiv = document.getElementById("personajeZelda");
            personajeZeldaDiv.onclick = personajeZeldaClick;
        }

        function moverPersonaje(x, y) {
            linkX = x;
            linkY = y;
        }

        function dibujaCanvas() {
            pant.drawImage(backgroundImg, 0, 0, anchoPantalla, altoPantalla);
            pant.drawImage(sprite, indiceX * 32, indiceY * 32, 32, 32, linkX, linkY, 90, 90);

            pant.fillStyle = 'white';
            pant.font = 'italic bold 18pt Times New Roman';
            pant.fillText("Tecla Presionada: " + teclap + ", X: " + linkX + " Y: " + linkY, 10, 30, (anchoPantalla - 10));

            linkX = Math.min(Math.max(linkX, 0), anchoPantalla - 90);
            linkY = Math.min(Math.max(linkY, 0), altoPantalla - 90);

            if (personajeAnimado) {
                frameCount++;
                if (frameCount >= velocidadAnimacion) {
                    indiceX = indiceX + 1;
                    if (indiceX > 4) {
                        indiceX = 0;
                    }
                    frameCount = 0;
                }
            }

            requestAnimationFrame(dibujaCanvas);
        }

        function onKeyDown(event) {
            teclap = event.keyCode;

            switch (teclap) {
                case 83:
                    linkY = linkY + 10;
                    indiceY = 0;
                    break;
                case 65:
                    linkX = linkX - 10;
                    indiceY = 1;
                    break;
                case 87:
                    linkY = linkY - 10;
                    indiceY = 2;
                    break;
                case 68:
                    linkX = linkX + 10;
                    indiceY = 3;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            personajeAnimado = true;
        }

        function onKeyUp(event) {
            personajeAnimado = false;
        }

        function tocarZelda() {
            if (!zeldaTocada) {
                zeldaTocada = true;
                jugadorStats.aumentarAtaque(10); // Aumenta el ataque del jugador en 5
                alert("EL MUNDO ESTA EN PELIGRO Y ES PELIGROSO IR SIN ARMAS. TOMA ESTA ESPADA PARA DEFENDERTE. Ahora tu subio " + jugadorStats.ataque);
                // Puedes agregar aquí la lógica adicional que desees.
            } else {
                alert("¡Ya has hablado con Zelda!");
            }
        }

        // Función que se ejecuta cuando se hace clic en el personaje de Zelda
        function personajeZeldaClick() {
            alert("¡Has hecho clic en Zelda!");
            // Puedes agregar aquí la lógica que deseas ejecutar al hacer clic en Zelda.
        }

        // Función que se ejecuta cuando se hace clic en la imagen del ladrón
// Función que se ejecuta cuando se hace clic en la imagen del ladrón
function tocarLadron() {
    if (!ladronTocado) {
        ladronTocado = true;
        
        // Guarda los datos en el LocalStorage antes de redirigir
        localStorage.setItem("vida", jugadorStats.vida);
        localStorage.setItem("ataque", jugadorStats.ataque);
        
        // Redirige al usuario a batallaladron.html
        window.location.href = 'ladronbatalla.html';
    } else {
        alert("¡Ya has tocado al ladrón!");
    }
}

        function mostrarStats() {
            alert("Vida: " + jugadorStats.vida + "\nAttack: " + jugadorStats.ataque);
        }
    </script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Todo aquello que sea catalogado como `"Basado en opiniones"` segun como funciona stack overflow no es adecuado como pregunta, no lo digo yo, son los propios usuarios a los que no les gusta responder preguntas basadas en opiniones, en mi caso no tendria problema, pero como eres nuevo usuario te indico que las preguntas basadas en opinones no tienen cabida aqui en la comunidad y normalmente las tildan en negativo.

Comment: Por otro lado, algo que si comparto con las personas de stack overflow es que se indica que las preguntas no deben ser muy largas y deben ser limitadas a un problema en especifico, en este caso, lo que deberias hacer es tratar de hacer un resumen del codigo o explicarnos que comportamiento estas obteniendo y el resultado que deseas, tambien ten en cuenta que en la comunidad nosotros no generamos codigo que no existe o no ha hecho el usuario (el cual es tu caso porque no veo que hayas colocado algo referente a colisiones en el codigo y juso preguntas por eso).

Comment: Nosotros nos limitamos mas bien, a que a  partir de un codigo que ya tengas y no este funcionando o no este haciendo lo que debe, a dar una solucion al problema con el que te encuentras, no le estariamos haciendo ningun favor al usuario si lo que hacemos es generar codigo sin que el usuario haya pensado previamente en una solucion o implementacion del codigo, al contrario, estariamos haciendo un maleficio ya que inhibimos la capacidad de desarrollo de logica del usuario, por eso mismo nos limitamos a algo que ya posees, asumiendo que ya lo haz intentado.

Comment: Para mas informacion, como nuevo usuario te invito a pasarte por el [tour] y de paso leer [ask], saludos.

Comment: Un consejo sencillo es que, como se trata de colisiones en 2D, una de las implementaciones mas faciles que puedes hacer es que a la hora de que te vas a mover, en vez de mover directamente el personaje, guardes las coordenadas actuales del personaje y predigas el siguiente movimiento y verifiques si las coordenadas del personaje y el otro objeto coinciden, si es asi, anulas el movimiento ya que hay colision, si no es asi permites que se mueva x o y unidades dependiendo de si el movimiento es horizontal o vertical, para ello debes tener en cuenta la hitbox de ambos objetos.